# Factoring and properties of variables with certain range values

Tags: logic, factoring

Given that the 6 numbers $a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6$ are integers from 0~9 and
$a1 + a2 + a3 = a2 + a4 + a6$,  we must present
$\overline a6\overline a5\overline a4\overline a3\overline a2\overline a1$ as a 6 digit number, what are the values for A, B, C, D, E, F and G?

$\overline a6\overline a5\overline a4\overline a3\overline a2\overline a1$  = $11( [ABCD]a6 + [EFG]a5 + [HI]a4 + [J]a3 + a2)$

There is a overbar over
$\overline a6\overline a5\overline a4\overline a3\overline a2\overline a1$   and i do not know what it means.

[ABCDEFGHIJ] are just any number from 0 to 9 or the minus sign (-), each letter correspond to 0 to 9 or minus (-).

From the answer sheet ABCD= 9091, EFG= 909, HI=91, J=9

I realized that i made some mistakes in the presentation so i edited the original question and will also post the original in japanese.
[image]
I do not know what tag i should add to this question, sorry if there is no connection between the question and the tags.

Comment: Sounds like a very interesting question, which I would like to attack, but can't because of the awkwardness of your presentation.  Please edit your question, expressing all Math with [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).  Also, please specify whether (for example) a 6 digit number is allowed to have its leftmost digit $= 0$.  Finally, re: "*There is a overbar over (a6a5a4a3a2a1) and i do not know what it means*" I don't know of any universal meaning to (for example) the expression $\overline{123}$.  Is the source of the question available online?

Comment: Normally, an expression like $1.\overline{123}$ is used to signify a repeating decimal, such as $1.123123123\cdots$.  I have never seen such an expression used on an integer (i.e. used on the digits to the **left** of the decimal place).

Comment: I translated that question from a japanese  math book, i do not think my translation is wrong but i am certain my presentation was weird. I will use MathJax and upload the question in japanese.

Comment: I expect that the overbar over $a_6a_5a_4a_3a_2a_1$ means that this is a 6-digit number made by concatenating the $a_i$ rather than the product of the $a_i$.

Comment: Is leftmost digit allowed to $= 0$?

Comment: yes, any a can equal any number from 0 to 9. I will also post the values of ABCDEF and G, i know the results from the answer sheet, i just want to know how to solve it or what exactly i need to do.